# Is there way to pass the result of response to another page, using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have problem passing the result to the another page of blade.php using ajax and laravel,

**I have two page,**

1. The first page http://localhost:8000/peoplegallery
2. http://localhost:8000/peoplegallery_album/ and the id

**Scenario:**

In the first page, you can see on that page are the list of album

Example.

1. Album1/  1
2. Album2/  2
3. Album3/  3

**Example Output**. if I click the calgarey album with id of 1 all the images inside of that must send to the peoplegallery_album

[image: Output first page]

So now my page transferred to http://localhost:8000/peoplegallery_album/1

Now the problem after I transferred http://localhost:8000/peoplegallery_album/1, why on response has no result.

I have here my codes on my first page where I list all the albums,

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'http://localhost:8000/api/peoplegallery',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success:function(response) {



            var peoplegallery = response[0].gallery_table;
            $.each(peoplegallery, function (index, el) {

                var stringify_list_gallery = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(el));
                var gallery_file = stringify_list_gallery['file'];
                var people_gallery_image = '<img src=/storage/' + gallery_file + ' class="d-block w-100">';
                var gallery_id = stringify_list_gallery['content_id'];
                var gallery_content_title = stringify_list_gallery['content_title'];
                var gallery_event_dated = stringify_list_gallery['event_dated'];

                var peoplegallery_data;

                peoplegallery_data = 
                '<div class="col-md-4">\
                    <div class="card" style="margin-left:20px;">\
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="/storage/'+gallery_file+'" alt="Card image cap" style="height:200px;">\
                        <div class="card-body">\
                             <h5 class="card-tilte">\
                                <a href="/peoplegallery_album/'+gallery_id+'" class="clicked_albums" data-id='+gallery_id+' style="color:black; font-weight: 500;">'+gallery_content_title+'</a>\
                             </h5>\
                        </div>\
                        <div class="card-footer">\
                            <small class="text-muted"><i class="icon ion-md-calendar" style="font-size:15px; color:#800000;"></i><i class="far fa-calendar-check"></i> '+gallery_event_dated+'</small>\
                        </div>\
                    </div>\
                    <br><br>\
                </div>\
                ';

                $('#list_peoplegallery').append(peoplegallery_data);

            });


        },
        error:function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

So now I need to create a function, to get the attribute id of album once i clicked that I will pass the ID to my api url. once success the result will send to the peoplegallery_album/1

So this is my codes for that

```
    $(document).ready(function(){   
    $(document).on('click','.clicked_albums',function(e) {
        var album_id= $(this).data('id');
        $.ajax({
            url:'http://localhost:8000/api/peoplegallery_album/'+ album_id,
            type:'get',
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            success:function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error:function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });

    }); 
});
```

My Controller Look likes this,

```
    public function peoplegallery_album($id)
{


    $get_title = DB::select('SELECT content_title,event_place,DATE_FORMAT(event_date, "%M %d, %Y") as event_dated FROM content_structure WHERE content_id = ? AND status = ? ',[$id,'Active']);

    $get_image = DB::select('SELECT cid,image,created_at FROM album_category WHERE cid = ?',[$id]);



    return response()->json(array(['logic_title' => $get_title,'get_image' =>$get_image]));
}
```

And my api route look this,

```
    Route::get('peoplegallery','api\UserController@peoplegallery');
Route::get('peoplegallery_album/{id}','api\UserController@peoplegallery_album');
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should get album id in the first page where you are getting the album

Comment: as you can see Ali i already get the attribute of id and has value,